# set_mempolicy from a different process

Tags: linux, memory, system-calls, numa, numactl

For NUMA machines, Linux provides the 
[`set_mempolicy`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/set_mempolicy.2.html) system call that allows a process to define its preferred NUMA node for memory allocations.

Is there some similar function that allows to change the memory policy of another running process? So something like this `set_mempolicy(pid, ...)` where `pid` corresponds to a different running process?

Note, that the other process (the one I want to change its memory policy) is already running and I have no control over it. So a solution like this:

```
set_mempolicy(...);
fork(); // now new process has the same memory policy
```

is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. create a cpuset with `mems` containing the desired node(s), and `memory_migrate` containing `1`
2. write the process' PID into the cpuset's `tasks` file

New allocations by the process will be fulfilled according to the cpuset's `mems` config, and existing pages will be migrated when the task is added to the set.

NB. This feels like a serverfault Q/A really, but your can write your cpuset management in C if it makes you feel better.

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways to implement given that I assume that you are unable to change the program.

1. Implement what NUMA policy would achieve by in userspace. It is possible to move pages for a process between different NUMA nodes. See [migratepages](https://github.com/jmesmon/numactl/blob/master/migratepages.c). I'd imagine you'd have to run this once in a while.
2. Otherwise, you can attach via gdb and set the policy. Note, I am not 100% certain if this will affect pages already allocated. You might have to run migratepages before this step.

Create a function that sets your preferred numa policy:

**inject.c**

```
#include "inject.h"

void inject(){
   printf("Changing memory policy\n");
   unsigned long nodemask = 1L << 1;
   set_mempolicy(MPOL_PREFERRED, &nodemask, 3);
}
```

**inject.h**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <numaif.h>
extern void inject();
```

**libinject.so**

```
gcc -c -Wall -Werror -lnuma -fPIC inject.c
gcc -shared -o libinject.so inject.o -lnuma
```

** Attach to pid and call the function you have defined **

```
gdb -p pid
(gdb) call __libc_dlopen_mode("/path_to/libinject.so", 0x0002)
(gdb) call  inject()
```

I have verified that I am able to change numa policy via /proc/pid/numa_maps ( changed from default to prefer:1 ) but I am not too familiar with numa to say that change is effective.

Please note that this is invasive process and hopefully there is a simpler alternative.